# How to unittest two function return values in a function using python unitttest

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a function in a python program which does a function call twice:

```py
def add_user(uname,dserver,pwd,dinstance,proc1, query1):
        db_conn = db_connect(uname,dserver,pwd,dinstance)
        if db_conn is not_conn:
            print("Failed to connect")
            sys.exit(-1)
        db_conn.run_proc(proc1)
        if db_conn.error_msg:
            print("Failed procedure")
            sys.exit(-1)
        db_conn.run_query(query1)
        if db_conn.err_msg:
            print("Failed query")
            sys.exit(-1)
```

Now the unit test is as follows:

```py
    @patch('mydir.proj_dir.db_execu.db_connect')
    def test_add_user(self, mock_conn):
        mock_conn.return_value.not_conn.return_value = True
        mock_conn.return_value.run_proc.return_value = True
        mock_conn.return_value.run_query.return_value = True
        mock_conn.return_value.err_msg.side_effect= [True, False]
        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
            add_user(name,dserver,pwd,dinstance,proc1, query1)
        print("failed query")
```

---

My objective is to test the second error condition. But after adding side_effect it only going to first condition which is displaying as "Failed procedure". I want to test "Failed Query" condition. First two error conditions I have tested but the third one is failing and calling the second condition always. Please advise.

Comment: print("Failed Query") is not executing as in coverage its not covering. Please note I am using logger.info in place of print but for example I have added print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not super clear what you're asking exactly. You're calling `add_user` only once so you're only testing a single "path", you need to call it multiple times to test multiple "paths" through it.

That aside, there's a huge issue with your understanding of `mock` `return_value` and `side_effect` configure mocks *as callables*, when accessing attributes but not calling them, you're just getting the next mock in the chain, you're not using any of your configuration. mock also supports configuring some of the "magic methods" of the data model, but it *does not support* configuring `__getattr__` (the "simple" attribute access) as that's used internally by mock.

As a result, you should only use mock to patch / replace `db_connect` to return a pseudo-connection, but rather than a mock that pseudo-connection should be a *fake*: an object you build yourself which looks like a connection but behaves however you want it e.g.

```py
class PseudoConnection:
    def __init__(self, fail_proc=False, fail_query=False):
        self._fail_proc = fail_proc
        self._fail_query = fail_query
        self.err_msg = None # or error_msg, or both

    def run_proc(self, proc):
        self.err_msg = self._fail_proc
    def run_query(self, query):
        self.err_msg = self._fail_query
```

Then you just configure `mock_conn.return_value = PseudoConnection(True, False)` to test the first case and `mock_conn.return_value = PseudoConnection(False, True)` for the second.

Also as hinted by the comment you're accessing both `error_msg` and `err_msg`, and only attempting to configure `err_msg`. I don't know which is right, but I doubt both are.